# RewriteRule on two directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to keep the user-end pages and the backend pages seperated by adding `cms/` in front of the URL. My `.htaccess` file looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ cms/index.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

My directory looks like this :

```
> Project
   > cms
      index.php
      cms_page1.php
      cms_page2.php
   > pages
      page1.php
      page2.php
      page3.php
.htaccess
index.php
```

In my outer `index.php` I include al the pages in `pages` folder by the URL parameter `url`. Those will be for the user-end pages. I'm doing this because in that index page I also have the styling and navigation for all the pages. I want to do the same thing for the pages in the `cms` folder.

When I go to `www.mysite.com/cms/`, it goes to the index page in the cms directory like it is supposed to. But when I go to  `www.mysite.com/cms/cms_page1`, it goes to the outer index file and the `url` parameter in that file is `cms/cms_page1`. But what I want it to do is this: `cms/index.php?url=cms_page1` so it opens the `index.php` in the cms directory and then includes the `cms_page1` page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is happening. You should [enable logging](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog) so you can see how URLs are being rewritten.

I suspect it has to do with the order of your rules, and that you're not stopping once certain rules match.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ cms/index.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

Adding the `L` flag [stops any other rules being applied](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l).